# Why laravel does not update files on its own during an upgrade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-upgrade

Today I updated to **laravel 5.7** and I don't know if you have to do things manually for an upgrade or I did not know how to upgrade.

But I noticed that when I updated to laravel 5.7 and ran `composer update` it did not change the directory structure:

```
old: /resources/assets/saas and /resources/assets/js
new: resources/saas and resources/js
```

Also, the new packages for eg. **beyondcode/laravel-dump-server** were not included but I had to add it myself.

Also, the `webpack.mix.js` file was not updated and was still pointing to `resources/assests/` rather than `resources/`

So do you have to do these things **manually** or am I doing something **wrong**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to make the changes to "your" application yourself. Everything that isn't the `vendor` folder is basically your application. There really is no link between `laravel/laravel` and your application after `composer create-project ...` has ran. You are making adjustments to your application to compliment changes to the framework, `laravel/framework`.

Just because there is a change in the structure of a default install of a new version does not mean that you have to follow that at all. If a change is needed it will be in the upgrade guide. If it is not it is not needed.

Your application is just code that loads and uses the framework, like any other composer package.